# Visual Studio Error: MSB6003: Could not load file or assembly. File not found

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2017

I was programming on Visual Studio last week. I could compile and test my Windows C# Form Application normally, until the following error started to show up:

> D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Roslyn\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(84,5): error MSB6003: The specified task executable "csc.exe" could not be run. Could not load file or assembly 'System.IO.FileSystem, Version=4.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I did some research and tried to add the files manually to the References. I even tried to unninstall and install Visual Studio 2017 Community again. Same error.

There were no updates or anything that should have caused this, as far as I am concerned.

Comment: Have you tried re-installing the .net framework ? Which version you're using ?

Comment: @DimitarTsonev Windows Form doesn't exist on .NET Core, so you don't have to assume

Comment: Does the same happen on a blank new project?

Comment: @DimitarTsonev Accordingly to the Project Properties, the target framework is .NET Framework 4.6.1. Haven't tried to reinstall yet.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Yes, same on a blank new project.

Comment: create a copy of the project and try to delete the Licence file from the project

Comment: I have the same issue now,  what did you do to resolve it?

Comment: @Wegged I installed the newest version of the .NET Framework (4.7.1) and it worked